# Where is the text selection tool in qpdfview?

Tags: pdf

This is literally the most basic tool in a PDF viewer and it should be available in the top menu as the first tool. I can't find it in qpdfview? where is it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In qpdfviewer after selecting your pdf, go to Edit > Copy to Clipboard and select the text your require using the cross-hairs tool.

You should note that the ordinary selection tool and editing capability you might otherwise expect doesn't exist in qpdfview.

Comment: What if I want to take part of a sentence which starts at 2 words to the end of one line and ends at the 2nd word of next line? Does this mean I have to copy the whole lines and remove unwanted words?

Comment: @KennetCeleste That would appear to be the case. It's quite a rudimentary tool.

Comment: @KennetCeleste if that answers your question, perhaps you would be kind enough to mark it as accepted.

Comment: Add something like "the ordinary selection tool doesn't exist in qpdfview" to your answer for people coming here looking for this feature and I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @KennetCeleste Done. Thanks, that makes it clearer

Comment: Easier to hold down the Shift key, and then just press&drag the mouse, as the other answer suggests.

Answer (score 8):

You can hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and then drag to copy the text to the clipboard.

The cross-hair appears as soon as you press down the left mouse button, while holding <kbd>Shift</kbd>.
The shortcut can be modified under:
Edit -> Settings -> Modifiers -> Mouse button modifiers -> Copy to clipboard